# why we call delegate using class name?? Why can't it list out in class Object list?

Tags: c#, delegates

See the example below...

```
public class Test
  {
    public delegate void Logger(string s);

    public void Process(Logger logger)
    {
      if (logger!= null)
      {
        logger("Process Started");
      }
      if (logger != null)
      {
        logger("Process End");
      }
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    public static void LogMe(string s)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Test obj = new Test();
      Test.Logger del = new Test.Logger(LogMe);
      obj.Process(del);
    }
  }
```

Here Delegate Logger is written in class Test ... when I create the object of Class Test i.e. obj... the delegate Logger is not listed there and when tried using class name I'm able to get the Logger.

I know the delegate concepts but I just want to understand why delegate is not listed in obj list.

Comment: So, if I am understanding you correctly, you mean to ask why you have to call `new Test.Logger(LogMe)` instead of just `new Logger(LogMe)`?

Comment: @lonewolf I guess so - bakshay: it's the same as with nested-classes - if you don't want this behavior then just move the delegate outside the class.

Comment: @lonewolf and @CarstenKonig According to me bakshay is asking that why `obj.Logger` is not coming even if its under Test Class.

Comment: Correct Sandeep.. I want to know why I cant get obj.Logger...

Comment: @bakshay : I think Peter Duniho has answered your doubt, Please go through that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I create the object of Class Test i.e. obj... the delegate Logger is not listed there and when tried using class name I'm able to get the Logger

A type nested within another type is not an instance member. Even though the keyword `static` is not applied to the declaration of the nested type, in some sense it's still "static". (Though, it's not a run-time member in the sense that you could call a method or access a field or property, so I'm not sure I would really consider it a "static member" either).

More basically, the delegate type `Logger` is not in any way a per-instance member of the class. I.e. each instance cannot have a different `Logger`. So it would not make any sense to access the `Logger` type through an instance reference.

And for any member of a class that isn't per-instance, you access it by using the type name instead. E.g. `Test.Logger`.

If the delegate type is in some way unique to `Test` and is closely tied to the public API of `Test`, then perhaps the nested type makes sense here. That said, I tend to try to avoid public nested types, using them only when it seems *really*, strongly the right thing to do, mainly because of this specific issue. I don't like having to quality type names with a containing type name. :)

You do have some alternatives:

- Don't even declare a custom delegate type. Just use a predefined one. In your example, `Action<string>` would work just as well.
- Don't nest the type. Then it need be only qualified with the namespace, which of course you can make implicit with a `using` statement.
- Alias the type. E.g. you can write `using Logger = MyNamespace.Test.Logger;` at the top of a source code file where you want to use the type, and then you can use it with just the shorter `Logger`. (Replace `MyNamespace` with whatever your actual fully-qualified namespace for the type is, of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you were to mention the delegate outside of the test class at the name space level:

```
namespace StackOverflow{
  public delegate void Logger(string s);
  public class Test
  {
  }
}
```

you would be able to access the Logger type without the prefix of the test class. Partly because we have often seen Delegate as a nested type we don't realize its a type and can stand its own in the namespace.